What is the inverse function of $x\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i e^{-a_i x}}{1+e^{-a_i x}}$?
I want to find the inverse expression of the following:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i e^{-a_i x}}{1+e^{-a_i x}} = T$$
$a_i , i \in\{1,2,...,n\} $ is known and $T$ is also known
I want to find $x$ in terms of $a_i$ and $T$.
$x \approx f(T,a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$.
I am not looking for an exact function; even an approximate is good enough. I am solving an optimization problem, and I want to know if such an $x$ can be found in terms of $T$ and $a_i$


Why would $x\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i e^{-a_i x}}{1+e^{-a_i x}}$ be injective? (and what is its range?) 2) (What) did you try for $n=2$? Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.


The fraction is the derivative of the denominator wrt to x, Both sides can be integrated wrt to x, yielding the sum of the logs of $1+e^{-i a_k x}$ - or the log of the product - to be equal to $T x$, As a transcendent equation it can be solved for $x$ by numerical inversion only.

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i\, e^{-a_i x}}{1+e^{-a_i x}}- T$$
We have
$$F(0)=\frac 12\sum _{i=1}^n a_i-T \qquad 
F'(0)=-\frac 14 \sum _{i=1}^n a_i^2 \qquad F''(0)=0$$
$$F^{(3)}(0)=\frac 18 \sum _{i=1}^n a_i^4\qquad 
F^{(4)}(0)=0\qquad F^{(5)}(0)=-\frac 14 \sum _{i=1}^n a_i^6$$
$$F^{(6)}(0)=0\qquad F^{(7)}(0)=\frac {17}{16}  \sum _{i=1}^n a_i^80\qquad F^{(8)}(0)=0$$
I am sure that you see thé pattern.
Now, for an approbation, use on single itération of a Newton-like mthod startjng AT
